# C# Listbox on web form Selected Items shows null

Tags: c#, asp.net, select, listbox

I am trying to do a web app with ASP.net WEB forms, using C#, i have a listbox that is populated with data from an SQL table, I need to send the selected items to a string, I wrote a method to have a select all checkbox, when all is selected I get all the data as expected, but if a select just 1 ore 3 or 5 items individually, I get Null references.

this is the code on the Button

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    foreach (ListItem value in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        if (value.Selected)
        {
            Label1.Text += value.ToString() + ", ";
        }    
    }
```

This is the code on the html file.

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:ListBox ID="Listbox1" runat="server" Height="168px" SelectionMode="Multiple" Width="168px" OnSelectedIndexChanged="Hidrologias_SelectedIndexChanged">            
        </asp:ListBox>
    </ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
      <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Descp_Casos" EventName="SelectedIndexChanged"  />    
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel9" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox21" runat="server" OnCheckedChanged="Selec_Todo" Text="Selecionar Todos" AutoPostBack="True"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

and this is the method I use to select all

```
protected void Selec_Todo(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
    ListBox1.SelectionMode = ListSelectionMode.Multiple;
    if (CheckBox21.Checked)
    {
        foreach(ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = true;   
        }
    }
    else if (!CheckBox21.Checked)
    {
        foreach (ListItem item in ListBox1.Items)
        {
            item.Selected = false;
        }
    }
```

some guidance please.

Comment: are you familiar with Postbacks. use the debugger and put break points in the Page_Load event and you will probably see what's going on.. also set your mode for the Update panel to Always or Conditional